# How to Login with username, email, phone number

Tags: html, laravel

This is my code and i get this error.

```
<input id="login" type="text" class="form-control {{ @error->has('phone')  @error->has('email')  @error->has('name') ? 'is-invalid' : '' }}" name="email" value="{{ old('phone') ?: old('email') ?: old('name') }}" required autofocus>
```

**syntax error, unexpected '<'**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a OR statement to check multiple conditions:

```
<input id="login" type="text" class="form-control {{ (@error->has('phone') || @error->has('email') ||  @error->has('name')) ? 'is-invalid' : '' }}" name="email" value="{{ old('phone') ?: old('email') ?: old('name') }}" required autofocus>
```