# Login with username, email or phone using Laravel 6.*

Tags: php, laravel, authentication

I am using Laravel 6.* and I am trying to change Laravel auth code by making the user able to login with email or username or phone number. I have updated the database adding phone number column. I have tried some methods on internet but I had only errors.

This is a part of code in login.blade.php

```
 <div class="card-body">
                    <form method="POST" action="{{ route('login') }}">
                        @csrf

                        <div class="form-group row">
                            <label for="email" class="col-md-4 col-form-label text-md-right"></label>

                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                <input id="email" type="email" class="form-control @error('email') is-invalid @enderror" name="email" value="{{ old('email') }}" required autocomplete="email" autofocus placeholder="Phone, email or username">

                                @error('email')
                                    <span class="invalid-feedback" role="alert">
                                        <strong>{{ $message }}</strong>
                                    </span>
                                @enderror
                            </div>
                        </div>
```

I tried to add this code in login.blade.php:

```
<input id="login" type="text" class="form-control {{ (@error->has('phone')  @error->has('email')   @error->has('name')) ? 'is-invalid' : '' }}" name="email" value="{{ old('phone') ?: old('email') ?: old('name') }}" required autofocus>
```

But it shows this error

```
syntax error, unexpected '<'
```

Comment: Looks like the same https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66505888/how-to-login-with-username-email-phone-number